# GitHub action runs with no error but does not populate xml file

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I'm very new to GH workflows. I have this yaml code that seems to be formatted correctly. GH even seems to be running it properly on schedule. But the xml file that should be modified doesn't get modified. When I run this locally it works. Any ideas?

```
name: UpdateRSSfeed

on:
  schedule:
    # Set the cron schedule to your desired interval (e.g. every day at 12:00 UTC).
    - cron: '0 8 * * *'
      timezone: America/Vancouver
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  update-feed:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      # Give the default GITHUB_TOKEN write permission to commit and push the
      # added or changed files to the repository.
      contents: write
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your script can access it.
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Set up Python and install dependencies.
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.9' # Replace with your desired Python version.

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip3 install -r requirements.txt

      # Run the Python script to generate the RSS feed.
      - name: Generate RSS feed
        run: python3 feed-create.py > filtered-rss-feed.xml

      # Commit the updated RSS feed to the GitHub Pages branch.
      - name: Commit changes
        uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
        with:
          commit_message: "UpdateRSSfeed"
          commit_options: "--no-verify"
```